# Problem installing sqlite3-ruby on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, sqlite3-ruby

I'm getting error while trying to install sqlite3-ruby gem:

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1.gem 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

Same using:

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1
```

And that worked:

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1-x86-mswin32-60.gem
```

However I discovered I had had installed sqlite-ruby-1.2.5

Well my question is how 'gem' is installing these things? Why it can't choose sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1-x86-mswin32-60.gem version automatically. Does 'gem' is aware of running on linux or windows? What is native extension for it and why it is failing to install predownloaded sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1.gem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people seem to be having this issue. I'm surprised this doesn't work out of the box, as I would have guessed cygwin+ruby+sqlite is a supercommon configuration. Anyway. Many people concentrate on sqlite3.h, which is what appears are missing in the error output. However, my problem was that gcc wasn't installed correctly. [Apparently](http://old.nabble.com/gcc-command-not-found-td27393452.html) gcc can fail to install correctly under cygwin. I fixed that and it was fine. Also, make sure you install libsql3-devel in cygwin.

Answer (score -2):

I've been down this road before.  I failed installing Ruby in Windows to work with Cygwin and [I failed on Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/156498/installing-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-10-04-a-living-nightmare).

What you do to save yourself the time and trouble is get a [VM running](http://www.virtualbox.org/) with a Linux image (Fedora seemed to work well) and work with Ruby in that.